# A special kind of sieve. Find lower bound for cardinality of a given set.

Tags: number-theory, inclusion-exclusion, sieve-theory

Let:

- $A=\{s,s+1,s+2,...,t\}$. Where $s,t$ are some fixed natural numbers
- $A(d,a,b)=\{m\in A: d|(m-a) \vee d|(m-b)\}$, where $d,a,b\in \mathbb{N}$
- $C$ be a finite subset of prime numbers
- $B =A\setminus \bigcup_{p\in C}A(p,a,b)$

> Calculate/find formula for $|B|$. If it is impossible, the find nontrivial lower bound.

Here is what i have tried:

$$|B|=|A|-\sum_{i=1}^{|C|}(-1)^i\sum_{\{i_1,...,i_s\}\subset C}|A(i_{1},a,b)\cap ...\cap A(i_{s},a,b)|$$

I have used here an inclusion-exclusion formula.

If we put $a=b=0$, then $A(d,a,b)=A(d,0,0)=\{m\in A:d|m\}$

And we see that for relativiely prime $Q$ and $W$ we get $A(Q\cdot W, 0,0)=A(Q,0,0)\cap A(W, 0,0)$.

Furthermore $|B|=\sum_{d|D}\mu(d)A(d,0,0)$, where $D$ is a product of all the elements from $C$, and $\mu$ is a Möbius function

It seems, that we can't make a similar result for any other $a, b$

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Regards

Comment: If $d \ \nmid \ a-b$ then $d$ can't divide both $m-a$ and $m-b$ so $A(d,a,b) = \lfloor (t-a)/d\rfloor-\lfloor (s-a-1)/d\rfloor +\lfloor (t-b)/d\rfloor-\lfloor (s-b-1)/d\rfloor$. If $d \ | \ a-b$ then $A(d,a,b) = \lfloor (t-a)/d\rfloor-\lfloor (s-a-1)/d\rfloor$. The lower bound will be of the form $x t-ys-z$.

Comment: Thank you. How to calculate for example $|A(d_1,a,b)\cap A(d_2,a,b)|$? How do you know that the lower bound will be of this form?

Comment: Your assertion is equivalent to: $(p_1\lor p_2)\land(q_1 \lor q_2)\iff (p_1\land q_1)\lor (p_2\land q_2)$  But this is not true.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Anything unclear

Comment: @mkultra, out of curiosity, where does this problem statement come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is what's expected but

$D =\prod_{p\in C} p$
$$|B|=\sum_{m\in [s,t],\ \gcd(m-a,D)=1 \ and \ \gcd(m-b,D)=1}1
$$ $$=\sum_{m\in [s,t]}\ \ \sum_{k| \gcd(m-a,D)}\mu(k)\sum_{l| \gcd(m-a,D)}\mu(l)$$ $$
 =\sum_{k| D}\sum_{l| D}\mu(k)\mu(l)\sum_{m\in [s,t], k | m-a \ and \ l|m-b}1
$$

If $\gcd(k,l)$ doesn't divide $a-b$ then  $$\sum_{m\in [s,t], k | m-a \ and \ l|m-b}1=0$$ otherwise $$\sum_{m\in [s,t], k | m-a \ and \ l|m-b}1=\frac{t-s}{lcm(k,l)} +O(1)$$
(here we can precompute the unique residue class $\bmod lcm(k,l)$ which satisfies $m\equiv a\bmod k,m\equiv b\bmod l$ if we want an exact formula)

Thus we are left with

$$|B|=\sum_{k| D,l| D, \gcd(k,l)|a-b}\mu(k)\mu(l) (\frac{t-s}{lcm(k,l)}+O(1))$$
$$ =(t-s)\eta +O(4^{|C|})$$